# Is there a way to disable Default Endpoint in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

Service stack by default has a [Default Endpoint](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Endpoints) enabled.

I can disable Soap endpoint with:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig 
{
    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Soap)
});
```

I want to be left with REST endpoint only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most functionality in ServiceStack is encapsulated in [modular and configurable plugins](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins). Since the pre-defined routes feature is **automatically pre-registered** for you (i.e. enabled by default) you need to explicitly remove it, just as you would any plugin, in your AppHost.Configure() with:

```
Plugins.RemoveAll(x => x is PredefinedRoutesFeature);
```

Warning: This is generally not recommended because it breaks the [built-in ServiceClient's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) from working since unless specified with explicit routes it falls back into using the pre-defined routes that are expected to exist.

Basically if you plan on using the .NET Service Clients I'd strongly advise not removing this functionality, I can't see any good reason to remove it as it's not apart of the common code-path so doesn't incur any performance penalties - it just limits the built-in functionality.